# Wordpress: Generate a join group button in groups-loop

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is what I have:

```
<ul id="popular">
      <?php while ( bp_groups() ) : bp_the_group(); ?>
<li <?php bp_group_class(); ?>>
       <div class="group-box">
    <div class="group-box-image-container">
        <a class="group-box-image" href="<?php bp_group_permalink() ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=full' ) ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="group-box-right">
        <div class="group-box-title"><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink() ?>"><?php $grouptitle = bp_get_group_name(); $getlength = strlen($grouptitle); $thelength = 20; echo mb_substr($grouptitle, 0, $thelength, 'UTF-8'); if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "..."; ?></a></div>
        <div class="group-box-details">
            <div class="gb-a">Active <?php echo bp_get_group_last_active(); ?></div>
            <div class="gb-m"><?php bp_group_member_count(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div><!--group-box ends-->
</li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

What I need: a link that allow every logged in member to join that group.

How can I do that? I have also the Invite anyone plugin activated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it:
In the file **groups-header.php** of the legacy theme I found the code:

```
do_action( 'bp_group_header_actions' );
```

The code above did the magic. Funny how wordpress words those actions... Not quite obvious is it?

Anyway, now it works. For the folks who need it, now you know it :)